# I want to display only unique categories from the list of all categories. What should I use in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, magento

I have so many categories on the page and using each function in jquery, I am listing all of them. I want to display only unique categories from the list and not the repeated ones. What should I use in jquery?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".rpc-post-category a" ).each( function( index, element ){
        console.log( jQuery( this ).text() );
    });
});
```

Note: I want a list of unique values from all text values.

Comment: It's very hard to provide you with a clear answer since we can't see any code.

Comment: post your html code too

Comment: Please share your complete code. Thanks

Comment: I have 30 to 35 <a href></a> tags and I want to find unique text values from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter to get unique value ref [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) .Hope this is what you are looking for,thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var result=[]
   $( ".class_name" ).each( function( index, element ){
    result.push( $( this ).text());
});
 result = result.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); 
 console.log(result)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="class_name">a</a>
<a href="#" class="class_name">b</a>
<a href="#" class="class_name">a</a>
<a href="#" class="class_name">c</a>
<a href="#" class="class_name">d</a>
```